# Bug: Edit Profile settings CSS issue for Privileges and Edit Developer CV

Tags: bug, design

Not sure if this is just me but in the `Edit Profile & Settings`, I notice there was a CSS issue for the links "Edit Developer CV" and "Privileges"

Upon looking at the CSS I think it's just that the `.external` class has a `display: inline-block` and should just be `display: block`? (feel free to ignore this I'm just doing my own thing)

Happening to me on Chrome 47

[image]

Comment: @Pops ah sorry you are right. If you'd like I can delete this question in favor of that one.

Comment: No need to apologize! No need to delete, either. I will close as dupe though, now that you agree it's the same bug. I know you were first, but for whatever reason that one got more traction.