# The ::after selector for external links is positioned with the text

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, hyperlinks

I was editing my profile when I noticed this:

### On SO

> [image]

### On Code Review.SE

> [image]

The `::after` content should have a little margin from the text itself. Currently, it hinders the readability.

Comment: repro-ed on Google Chrome, Edge and FireFox, all on Win10

Comment: MSO duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313118/icon-and-link-text-overlap-in-edit-profile-settings

Comment: Probable duplicate (but you have identified different causes and I haven't investigated yet): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271605/bug-edit-profile-settings-css-issue-for-privileges-and-edit-developer-cv